# Spring @ConfigurationProperties map with default entry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class where I would like to bind properties of the following form:

```
foo.x.prop1 = some_value
foo.x.prop2 = some_value

foo.y.prop1 = some_value
foo.y.prop2 = some_value
```

This is what the class looks like:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("")
class FooProperties {

     private Map<String, FooConfig> foo = new HashMap<>();

     ...

     static class FooConfig {

         private String prop1;
         private String prop2;

         ...
     }
```

The map will store `x` and `y` as keys. My question is: is it possible to have a binding for default properties:

```
foo.x.prop1 = some_value
foo.x.prop2 = some_value

foo.y.prop1 = some_value
foo.y.prop2 = some_value

// default for all others
foo.prop1 = default_value1
foo.prop2 = default_value2
```

I would be interested to know how this use case is handled in the Spring ecosystem in general? (I'm open to other property formats)

Comment: If you enter in youf FooConfig class default values `private String prop1 = "someDefault"` is that what you mean?

Comment: @bilak that would solve the issue when there are no external properties, but I still would like to have the possibility to control these default values in the application properties.